# Get data that's in a tag (HTML content)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="4.05"/>
```

Here's my HTML that I need to extract `4.05` from.

I'm using BeautifulSoup with Python.

#### EDIT:

I also need to use `itemprop="price"` because I have more than one `<meta content="x"/>`

```
soup.find("meta", {"itemprop":"price"})["content"]
4.05
```

Comment: Instead of putting "solved" at the end of your question, please consider accepting an answer by checking the green checkmark left of the question that helped you solve it. This will give a little bit of reputation to both you and the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

```
html = '<meta itemprop="price" content="4.05"/>'
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.find("meta")["content"]
4.05
soup.meta["content"]
4.05
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> text = '<meta itemprop="price" content="4.05"/>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> soup
<html><head><meta content="4.05" itemprop="price"/></head></html>
>>> soup.meta
<meta content="4.05" itemprop="price"/>
>>> soup.meta["content"]
'4.05'
>>>
```